# "Rhetorical Suggestion"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not clear about what does it mean by "rhetorical suggestion" in the following quote:

> Aristotle mentions that some people, before Thales, placed great
>   importance on water, but he credits Thales with declaring water to be
>   the first cause (Metaphysics 983b27–33), and he then later raises the
>   question of whether perhaps Hesiod was the first to look for a cause
>   of motion and change (984b23ff.). These suggestions are **rhetorical**:
>   Aristotle does not seriously imply that those he mentions are engaged
>   in the same sort of inquiry as he thinks Thales was.

Does it mean that Aristotle has only raised the question casually and he is not very much serious about it?

Or it means that Aristotle just wants to show grandeur for Hesiod?

Or it means that Aristotle in fact wants to refute this possibility and he is talking just "Is it possible that Hesiod be the such that"!? So, his tune is refuting.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's a usage I'm not entirely happy with. A rhetorical question is really a declaration wrapped up as a question, usually as an attempt to browbeat while seeming not to. But usually, it is not intended that the question be answered, as it is too obvious what the answer would be. I can't see that this works here; I'd say that this becomes POB as a non-standard usage. What is the point in raising a question with a transparent answer if it doesn't hammer home a truth?

Comment: Could you please provide proper attribution for what/whom you are quoting? Besides being proper protocol, it serves as part of the context.

Answer (score 1):

This part of Aristotle’s Metaphysics (literally ‘meta Ta Physica’ - what comes ‘after the Physics’), which is devoted to the origins and nature of reality as we know it.  We rely heavily on snippets like this, because the early and Byzantine Christians did an effective job destroying most of the works of the early cosmologists.  We cannot be sure of their exact motives, but the attempt to explain the origins and nature of the cosmos (culminating in the atomism of Democritus) without reference to a divine act of creation or at least in Genesis re-organisation) was not compatible with Christian dogma.

What we have here is the briefest *tour d’horizon* of the main pre-Socratic cosmologists.

Hesiod, to whom Aristotle refers here, was an early poet, best known for two major didactic epics:  The *Works and Days*(about how to farm) and *Theogony*.  The latter dealt with the origins of gods, men and so was a kind of polytheist cosmology.

Your commentator is, consequently, suggesting that Aristotle mentions Hesiod only to dismiss him, or at least that he is not taking him very seriously.

As to the expression /rhetorical suggestion itself, it sounds to me as if it is what lexicons of ancient Greek call a hapax legomenon (lit. once said - a one-off). It is derived from the widely known *rhetorical question*, which is not a real question.  When I was at school, my teachers were fine with this sort of creative use of language, provided I placed it in single quotes to warn the reader.  So I should say he should have written that “the suggestion was ‘rhetorical’”.

Personally, I think he is reading too much into Aristotle text.  Aristotle is a stickler for comprehensive coverage.  He leaves nothing out.  But Hesiod was indeed no metaphysician or cosmogonist.  He was relaying tradition as it came down to him.  Thales was trying to account for change without recourse to magic or miracle.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You have explained a single expression with in-depth manner and it really made it clear.
And, your comment also reveals your profound understanding of  the philosophy of that age. I am hopeful that this would keep going.

Comment: @MushrrafBaigAshraf You are welcome.